# Insert a var in JavaScript img tag

Tags: javascript, wordpress, owl-carousel

I use Owl Carousel in WordPress website and I want to use site URL dynamically to add nav imgs from theme URL to website.

This is the code:

```js
  $(".home-slider-wrapper").owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: false,
    loop: true,
    nav: true, // Show next and prev buttons
    dots: false,
    slideSpeed: 2500,
    smartSpeed: 1000,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
      }
    },
    navText: [
      '<img src="/assets/images/angel-left.svg" alt="angle left" class="owl-prev__img" width="16px" height="14px">',
      '<img src="/assets/images/angel-right.svg" alt="angle right" class="owl-next__img" width="16px" height="14px">',
    ],
  });
```

and in `functions.php` I write the code to get site URL dynamically and can access to site URL by:
`siteURLData.root_url`   and it works fine.

Maybe so simple but I want to know how to use `siteURLData.root_url` in navText src.

Comment: It's just a simple string concatenation, like `'string ' + variable + ' other string'`, or using template literal: `\`string ${variable} other string\``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, Thats silly that I think I cant use backticks to solve it simply:

```js
    navText: [
      `<img src="${siteURLData.root_url}/wp-content/themes/spaceventwp/assets/images/angel-left.svg" alt="angle left" class="owl-prev__img" width="16px" height="14px">`,
      `<img src="${siteURLData.root_url}/wp-content/themes/spaceventwp/assets/images/angel-right.svg" alt="angle right" class="owl-next__img" width="16px" height="14px">`,
    ],
```